# I made a terrible mistake with flagging for moderator attention! How can I reverse it?

Tags: support, new-users, flagging

There were two comments following this question, [How to disable folder view?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47350/how-to-disable-folder-view)

Both comments were good, and relevant to the question. I intended to up vote the second one, but accidentally clicked on the yellow comment flag for the one preceeding it. Then I tried to unclick the yellow flag, but only succeeding in clicking the yellow flag for the first comment! Both comments have been flagged now, and I can't undo the yellow flags! **What should I do?**

One of the comments was from a new user, the other comment was from a very nice, friendly, long-time user. **I MADE A MISTAKE!**

Comment: Happens to the best of us! (Well, not saying I'm the best, but it certainly has happened to me before
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of July 7, 2016, [the ability to retract a flag on a Question or Answer is now live on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/21960) and will be rolled out to the rest of the network "soon".

At present, there are no plans to expand this to comment flags, so [Sathya's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2438/354) still holds.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing to be done, you can't rescind a flag. We'll probably dismiss the flag without any action if there's nothing wrong with the comment

Comment: Okay, thanks! One comment was from Al Everett. He is a very nice person, and I know him (but only a little) external to SE. I don't want him to think I am being malicious by flagging his unobjectionable and in fact, helpful and appropriate comments. That is the reason for what might seem like anxiety.

Comment: Well for one, flagging is anonymous, so no one can see who flagged which post(except for Mods). Also, Mods aren't going to blindly approve each flag - we look at the situation, content and act on it. Mistakes happen once a while, nothing to worry about